# How to find and remove part of a string in Rails Console - ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activemodel, rails-console

I'm looking for a way in the rails console to find any values that finish with a particular string and remove that string from the value.

Something along the lines of:

```
Model.all.each{|x| x.duration.slice!(" weeks")}.where("duration IS NOT NULL")
```

So that values such as ***"47 weeks"*** simply become ***"47"***, but there isn't a Slice method for `ActiveRecord/ActiveModel` and I don't know the equivalent.

Any ideas??

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `where("column_name LIKE <matcher>")` syntax to search for models with the column having the matching substring:

```
matching_models = Model.where("duration LIKE '% weeks'")
```

Then iterate over the result, using `gsub` to replace the column value

```
matching_models.find_each do |model|
  model.update_column(:duration, model.duration.gsub(/ weeks$/, "")
end
```

Some relevant points:

- Use `find_each` instead of `each` as it will load data in batches to better use memory.
- `gsub` is used to replace the existing string. The `/ weeks$/` regex matches strings ending in " weeks".
- `model.update_column` is used instead of `update_attributes` to bypass `ActiveRecord` validations and callbacks. You can use `update_attributes` if you want to run validations and callbacks.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer works correctly but will get noticeably slow if you have a few thousand records ending with " weeks" or more, because Rails has to grab and instantiate all matching records from the table.

In general, it is preferable to **leave all work to the database engine**, if possible, which could be written like this:

```
Model.where("duration LIKE '% weeks'").
      update_all("duration = SUBSTRING(duration, 1, LENGTH(duration) - 6)")
# => UPDATE `models` SET `models`.`duration` = SUBSTRING(duration, 1, LENGTH(duration) - 6) WHERE (duration LIKE '% weeks')
```

This query will be much more performant and memory efficient if you have lots of records to update. It uses the [`update_all` Rails method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all) to run the UPDATE query on all matching records in the table and the [`SUBSTRING` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) to shorten the `duration` field by 6 characters, which is the length of the " weeks" string.

Answer (score 2):

As @BoraMa says, the accepted answer will take a long time for thousands of records and their answer works for MySQL so here's a PostgreSQL version:

```
Model.where("duration LIKE '% weeks'").
      update_all("duration = REPLACE(duration, ' weeks', '')")
```

Rather than trim the last 6 characters this just replaces " weeks" with an empty string. Your question mentions 'finish with a particular string' so here's the regex version which anchors to the end of the string:

```
Model.where("duration LIKE '% weeks'").
      update_all("duration = REGEXP_REPLACE(duration, ' weeks$', '')")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `column_name.to_i` to get **47** from string **47 weeks**